# Vue-cli - Getting Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\User\Project\VueJSapp' on npm run dev command

Tags: node.js, npm, vuejs2, npm-install, vue-cli

I am using vue-cli.
When I am starting the server with the command "npm run dev", I am getting the below error:-
[image: npm error]

Also, I am getting this error when I am running "npm Install" command.

Comment: Try deleting `node_modules` folder then `npm install` again.

Comment: is this a new cli project?

Comment: Yes, this is a new cli project.

Comment: Try to update Node.js to last version, There can be also some path length problems (but try first with new version of Node)

Comment: @lkbel I deleted the node_modules folder, but it doesn'twork. Getting the same error.

Comment: @V.Sambor I have tried updating the node version, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same happen to me when I was messing around with a new project, deleted the folder and tried again. I had to delete the parent folder and re-create it in order for this to work for me.